# IBM Portal Server System out Log format

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, portal, websphere-portal

I am searching for the default Log format of the IBM Portal Server used for the Systemout.log and SystemError.log files. I have referred many links to find it. From where Portal Server picks the Log format for the these log files?
And also Can we change this log formate?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the was admin console and go under
Application servers > WebSphere_Portal > WebSphere_Portal > JVM logs there you can pick either basic of advanced for the formatting

Comment: is it in a wp_profile folder? There is no chance to have a WebSphere_Portal folder within AppServer installation folder, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I am not sure quite what you are asking, but you can tell the log files to go wherever, but I was referring to the was admin console, wp_profile is usually its own directory,  but above is the navigation from within the console to get to change the log format